# Firebase emulator not facilitating/running new functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have three cloud functions, two of which have been deployed to my firebase project, one of which I've just added. I was hoping to test the new one locally before deploying, but when I try to use it I'm unable, and only the two already-deployed functions are useable.

Firebase emulator runs just fine on port `5001`, as per usual. I followed [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument_your_app_for_https_functions_emulation) and added `firebase.functions().useEmulator("localhost", 5001);` to the func I wanted to test locally:

already-deployed func example:

```js
// index.js
exports.addMessage = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest(...
```

not-yet-deployed func:

```js
// index.js
exports.testFunction = functions.useEmulator("localhost", 5001).https.onRequest(...
```

Then I went to `https://localhost:5001/{projectId}/us-central1/testFunction`, but the browser displayed a message saying only `addMessage` and my other deployed func was available for use. I also tried `http`, as was recommended in another thread.

Is there a step I'm missing here? Some kind of "local" deployment? I'm aware there's been some changes in firebase versions which could be messing things up, but I'm using the default imports/dependencies firebase installs when you run `firebase init`:

```js
// package.json
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
},

//index.js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
```

Comment: can you concise what are you trying to achieve and issue you are facing?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav Trying to run my functions locally via the emulator so I can test them first before deploying, rather than deploying to firebase, trying them, debugging them, deploying again etc.

Comment: can you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158010/firestore-firebase-emulator-not-running is  it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I think it could be. I'd disregarded the thread, because my emulator has always been working and that thread is from a user who couldn't load an emulator at all. But I ran `firebase setup:emulators:firestore` and now my newly-added function works. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer as directed by you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

1: Deploy your function in the firebase in order to get recognized.
you can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment) using `firebase deploy --only functions`

2: Make sure that  the emulator is installed by the following command: `firebase setup:emulators:firestore`. for this you can refer [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite) as mentioned :

> The emulators:start command will start emulators for Cloud Functions,
> Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database, and Firebase Hosting based on the
> products you have initialized in your local project using firebase
> init. If you want to start a particular emulator, use the --only flag.

For further reference you can follow up the stackoverflow thread [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56158010/firestore-firebase-emulator-not-running) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225382/cloud-firestore-emulator-not-running-when-testing-cloud-functions-locally) where similar issue has been raised by the OP which might be helpful.

Comment: `npm run build` is enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is `npm run build` in your `functions` folder. Editing your functions doesn't trigger a build automatically and doesn't recognize your new function. The reason that deploying works, is that it does trigger a build.

Comment: Upvoted! This is correct answer, because the accepted anwer will not working in case of updation of existing cloud function. I was struggling with this from 2 hours.

Comment: As I just confirmed after having the same issue, running `npm run build` and then running the firebase emulators will let you emulate the function locally

Answer (score 2):

EDIT, new answer:

Turns out you need to deploy the function to firebase once for the function to be recognised by the emulator.

Run `firebase deploy --only functions` and then emulate your db and you should see your function.

Previous answer:
After running `firebase setup:emulators:firestore` my newly-added function seems to work in the emulator.