# Why is admin.firestore.FieldValue undefined when running code in firebase emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

In my firebase cloud functions, I have upgraded firebase-admin to version 11.0.0 (from 9.12.0) and engines from 12 to 16. After that admin.firestore.FieldValue is undefined when I run my code in the emulator.

When I deploy the code it works correctly.

I like to test in the emulator. Is there anything I can do to make this work in the emulator?

My code:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// Remove user permissions
await firestore.doc(`/${projectsPath}/${projectKey}`).update({
        roUids: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
        rwUids: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
});
```

My package.json:

```
{
"name": "functions",
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
},
"main": "lib/src/index.js",
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "api2pdf": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.22.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.2.0",
    "googleapis": "^104.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mailchimp-api-v3": "^1.13.1",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "onedrive-api": "^1.0.1",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "php-serialize": "^3.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "16"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/node": "^16",
    "@types/php-serialize": "^3.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.4",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
},
"private": true
```

}

Comment: Can you try using `import { FieldValue } from "firebase-admin/firestore";` instead?

Comment: If I try import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'; I get Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-admin/firestore'

Comment: Please check the stackoverflow URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167159/firebase-emulator-not-facilitating-running-new-functions

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to update your import. 
This worked for me:

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
```

Same for TimeStamp

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1803)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue
```

You should import `FieldValue` in one of these ways:

```
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'
```

or

```
const { FieldValue } = require ("firebase-admin/firestore");
```

And then use directly `FieldValue`.

---

To fix your example:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { FieldValue } from 'firebase-admin/firestore'

// Remove user permissions
await firestore.doc(`/${projectsPath}/${projectKey}`).update({
        roUids: FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
        rwUids: FieldValue.arrayRemove(uidOfUserToDelete),
});
```